# Videos produced with ffmpeg don't have frame width or height properties?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following to produce my intermediate slideshow mp4 clips

```
ffmpeg    -r 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg      -i 01.jpg    -i 01.mp3    -codec:v libx264 -r 24    -codec:a copy -b:a 128k    -shortest -y  01.mp4
```

And the produced 01.mp4 plays OK however, the properties detail under Windows don't show any frame size width or height?  Why is that? This may be an issue, see below...

I also produced an intro clip in AfterEffect using H.264 to produce an MP4 file.

I later have problem when I try to concatenate these 01.mp4 ,02.mp4, 03.mp4 with the intro.mp4 using the command line

```
ffmpeg -f concat   -i MyFileList.txt  -c copy  -y output.mp4
```

The resulting output.mp4 video causes VLC player to crash right after it completes playing the intro segment.
my xx.jpg files are 1600x1200 and my intro.mp4 is 1920x1080 24fps so perhaps there is an issue there as well.

I am not able to make sense of the purple and yellow lines from ffmpeg output during the concat perhaps you can help interpret, the output is attached.

Feel free to change any of the ffmpeg options for the production of my slideshow temp files 01.mp4, .02.mp4, 03.mp4 ... or during the concat operation, it's been a lot of guess work on my part.

BTW, the reason I am using concat is because I thought at first ffmpeg would be able to iterate on images 01,02...jpg and matching them up with there 01,02,....mp3 sound files but apparently that is not possible with some command line like this :)

```
ffmpeg -i %02d.jpg -i %02d.mp3 .... output.mp4
```

Thank you.

===== output from concat follows:

```
ffmpeg version N-79000-g66edd86 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.102 /  6. 39.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000044c960] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'mylist.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2996 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2964 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2964 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 44100 Hz, mono, 32 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000028558c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235984, current: 120320; changing to 235985. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235985, current: 120832; changing to 235986. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235986, current: 121344; changing to 235987. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235987, current: 121856; changing to 235988. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235988, current: 122368; changing to 235989. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235989, current: 122880; changing to 235990. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235990, current: 123392; changing to 235991. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235991, current: 123904; changing to 235992. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235992, current: 124416; changing to 235993. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235993, current: 124928; changing to 235994. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235994, current: 125440; changing to 235995. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235995, current: 125952; changing to 235996. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235996, current: 126464; changing to 235997. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235997, current: 126976; changing to 235998. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235998, current: 127488; changing to 235999. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 235999, current: 128000; changing to 236000. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236000, current: 128512; changing to 236001. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236001, current: 129024; changing to 236002. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236002, current: 129536; changing to 236003. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236003, current: 130048; changing to 236004. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236004, current: 130560; changing to 236005. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236005, current: 131072; changing to 236006. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236006, current: 131584; changing to 236007. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236007, current: 132096; changing to 236008. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000028558c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236008, current: 132841; changing to 236009. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236009, current: 133353; changing to 236010. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236010, current: 133865; changing to 236011. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236011, current: 134377; changing to 236012. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236012, current: 134889; changing to 236013. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236013, current: 135401; changing to 236014. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236014, current: 135913; changing to 236015. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236015, current: 136425; changing to 236016. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236016, current: 136937; changing to 236017. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236017, current: 137449; changing to 236018. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236018, current: 137961; changing to 236019. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236019, current: 138473; changing to 236020. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236020, current: 138985; changing to 236021. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236021, current: 139497; changing to 236022. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236022, current: 140009; changing to 236023. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236023, current: 140521; changing to 236024. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236024, current: 141033; changing to 236025. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236025, current: 141545; changing to 236026. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236026, current: 142057; changing to 236027. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236027, current: 142569; changing to 236028. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236028, current: 143081; changing to 236029. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236029, current: 143593; changing to 236030. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236030, current: 144105; changing to 236031. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236031, current: 144617; changing to 236032. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000028558c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236032, current: 145363; changing to 236033. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236033, current: 145875; changing to 236034. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236034, current: 146387; changing to 236035. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236035, current: 146899; changing to 236036. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236036, current: 147411; changing to 236037. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236037, current: 147923; changing to 236038. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236038, current: 148435; changing to 236039. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236039, current: 148947; changing to 236040. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236040, current: 149459; changing to 236041. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236041, current: 149971; changing to 236042. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236042, current: 150483; changing to 236043. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236043, current: 150995; changing to 236044. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236044, current: 151507; changing to 236045. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236045, current: 152019; changing to 236046. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236046, current: 152531; changing to 236047. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236047, current: 153043; changing to 236048. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236048, current: 153555; changing to 236049. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236049, current: 154067; changing to 236050. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236050, current: 154579; changing to 236051. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236051, current: 155091; changing to 236052. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236052, current: 155603; changing to 236053. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236053, current: 156115; changing to 236054. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236054, current: 156627; changing to 236055. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00000000004ad480] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 236055, current: 157139; changing to 236056. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  309 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3986kB time=00:00:12.93 bitrate=2525.2kbits/s speed= 166x    
video:3927kB audio:50kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.232265%
```

===== Here is the output from ffprobe on intro.mp4

```
ffprobe version N-79000-g66edd86 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.102 /  6. 39.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3003 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2964 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

===== Here is the output of ffprobe on one of intermediate clips here 01.mp4

```
ffprobe version N-79000-g66edd86 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.102 /  6. 39.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1036 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1006 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 31 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

===== ffmpeg output when generating 01.mp4 when using the following suggested fix:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 01.jpg -i 01.mp3 -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24 -video_track_timescale 24000 -c:a copy -shortest -y 01.mp4

ffmpeg version N-79000-g66edd86 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.102 /  6. 39.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'S:\_W\ARP_WEB\RC\KIDS\QURAN\AAYAAT - Allah\01 AlKursi\BMP\01.JPG':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25065 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 96:96 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mp3 @ 00000000005d03a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'S:\_W\ARP_WEB\RC\KIDS\QURAN\AAYAAT - Allah\01 AlKursi\SND\01.MP3':
  Duration: 00:00:09.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0000000002b30c40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] profile Main, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] 264 - core 148 r2665 a01e339 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'S:\_VIDS_PRODUCTIONS\20110219 MUMTI CLIPS\20160311 Epic Quran Recitations\01.MP4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 24k tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.28.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 44100 Hz, mono, 32 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Past duration 0.639992 too large
Past duration 0.679985 too large
Past duration 0.719994 too large
Past duration 0.759987 too large
Past duration 0.799995 too large
Past duration 0.839989 too large
Past duration 0.879997 too large
Past duration 0.919991 too large
Past duration 0.959999 too large
Past duration 0.999992 too large
frame=   43 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   71 fps= 70 q=28.0 size=     133kB time=00:00:00.54 bitrate=2016.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.533x    
frame=  104 fps= 68 q=28.0 size=     144kB time=00:00:01.91 bitrate= 615.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=1.26x    
frame=  137 fps= 67 q=28.0 size=     154kB time=00:00:03.29 bitrate= 384.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=4 speed=1.61x    
frame=  170 fps= 67 q=28.0 size=     165kB time=00:00:04.67 bitrate= 289.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=1.84x    
frame=  203 fps= 66 q=28.0 size=     176kB time=00:00:06.04 bitrate= 238.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=7 speed=1.98x    
frame=  236 fps= 66 q=28.0 size=     186kB time=00:00:07.41 bitrate= 205.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=8 speed=2.08x    
frame=  269 fps= 66 q=28.0 size=     197kB time=00:00:08.79 bitrate= 183.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=9 speed=2.16x    
frame=  295 fps= 60 q=28.0 Lsize=     215kB time=00:00:09.87 bitrate= 178.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=11 speed=2.02x    
video:167kB audio:38kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.696121%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] frame I:2     Avg QP:11.38  size:144156
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] frame P:74    Avg QP:15.03  size:   194
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] frame B:219   Avg QP:24.20  size:   151
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  0.0%  0.0% 99.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] mb I  I16..4: 58.4%  0.0% 41.6%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.7%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.1%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:98.9%  L0:27.6% L1:72.4% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 31.2% 32.8% 29.4% inter: 0.0% 0.1% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] i16 v,h,dc,p: 75% 18%  5%  2%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 34% 25% 18%  4%  4%  4%  4%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] i8c dc,h,v,p: 68% 15% 13%  4%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] ref P L0: 99.3%  0.2%  0.3%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] ref B L0: 96.4%  3.5%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] ref B L1: 99.3%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 00000000005ba520] kb/s:218.52
```

Comment: The concat demuxer in copy mode, requires all streams to have the same properties i.e. framerate, video dimensions, codec properties..etc

Comment: In my source document the images are 4:3 ratio and will not convert nicely into a 16:9 ratio (they will stretch horizontally). Nonetheless, I went ahead and modified my PowerPoint exporter to produce 1920x1080 JPG images, however the resulting output.mp4 (intro+01+02+03) video still won't play correctly past the intro and crash.  Interestingly enough with nothing changed in my ffmpeg options script this time the 01,02 and 03.mp4 files do show 1920x1080 24fps in the Windows' property dialog detail tab. What else is going wrong?

Comment: What does `ffprobe intro.mp4` say?

Comment: @Mulvya I have added the ffprobe output to the main post as there are text and formatting limitations in these comments.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **1920x1080** JPGs you exported, use this command to generate each MP4 and then run concat as before:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 01.jpg -i 01.mp3 -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24 -video_track_timescale 24000 -c:a copy -shortest -y 01.mp4
```

If using 4:3 JPGs, use this command to generate **1920x1080** videos:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 01.jpg -i 01.mp3 -vf "scale=-1:1080,pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw)/2:(1080-ih)/2,setsar=1" -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24 -video_track_timescale 24000 -c:a copy -shortest -y 01.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you the concatenation now seems to be working and playing till the end. There are some warning messages see addendum to main post.   Perhaps you can comment how "-profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p  -video_track_timescale 24000" fix my guess work on the options :)

Finally, can ffmpeg morph the 1600x1080 images into 1920x1080 without distortion using I think "letterboxing" there are other techniques.  I have lots of these slide documents and I cannot consider redesigning them into 16:9 ratio.  Thanks.

Comment: So I think I resolved my 4:3 to 16:9 conversion starting with 1600x1200 bitmaps and by using your exact video options and adding to them -s 1920x1080  to produce 01_169.mp4, 02_169.mp4 and which play OK when I concatenate them with the intro.mp4.  Thanks again.  SET _OUT_V_PARAMS= -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24 -video_track_timescale 24000  -s 1920x1080

Comment: After thinking about it, I just added the size option  -s 1920x1080 directly to the first production of 01.mp4,02,03....clips  and the concatenation with the intro clip works equally well :)   IOW, do the transform from 4:3 bitmaps to 16:9 movie right from the start with the 4:3 slides bitmaps.

Comment: Do your slides get distorted using that method?

Comment: No they don't distort unless I add also -aspect 16:9 which I don't won't in this case :)  Are you surprised :) During some playbacks of the same output I see a momentary squeeze perhaps of the first frame as we transition from the intro to 01 clip but that the only artifact. It does not do it every time (perhaps it's a VLC thing).  I will see later on when I upload to youtube in the final production.

Comment: By "squeeze" I mean like I see the first glimpse of 01 clip go from a 16:9 to 4:3 ratio with the black left/right borders.  But it's not an issue I am not that picky :) I don't see that when transitioning from 01 to 02 and so on.

Comment: Use edited command to accommodate 4:3 pictures in a 1080p canvas.

Comment: Thanks that works equally well, I removed the -s 1920x1080 option.

Comment: What happens when you concat clips with different frame sizes like you originally did is that player has to reinitialize context during the transition to the segment with the differing clips. Not all players do that - either well or at all. So, unless your playback is only meant for VLC or accommodating players, you should use my latest command for 4:3 sources.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying :) I already adjusted my proto script with your magic -vf "scale=-1:1080,pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw)/2:(1080-ih)/2,setsar=1" :) in my most recent attempt and as an outsider to all this video stuff, the -s option seemed to produce a 1920x1080 frame video but in the inside your know it's different.  I appreciate your time and expertise thanks a million.